# Code issues regarding Ambiguous Permutations

Tags: c++, stl

Consider this question: [Ambiguous Permutation](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PERMUT2/). My code is written in **C++11 using G++ 4.7.2**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    int h;
    while((cin >> h) && (h!=0))
    {
        int num;
        bool c=true;
        vector<int> arr;
        while((cin >> num) && (h!=0))
        {
            arr.push_back(num);
            --h;
        }
        const auto n = arr.size();
        for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i)
        {
            if(arr[arr[i]-1] != (i+1))
            {
                c = false;
                cout << "Not Ambiguous\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        if(c==true)
            cout << "Ambiguous\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine as long as I enter every number in a newline. If I start providing inputs separated by white space (for permutation) then the code behaves unexpectedly. It demands an invalid input for the condition while((cin >> num) and exits after one round of input. Any suggestions for removing this issue? I was also wondering if using [STL Arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) would be good choice or not. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing C++ 4.7.2. Name it either GCC 4.7.2 if you're talking about the compiler, or C++98/C++03/C++11 if you are talking about the language.

Comment: @ybungalobill Done! Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking input incorrectly, specifically here-

```
    while((cin >> num) && (h!=0)) //WRONG!
    {
        arr.push_back(num);
        --h;
    }
```

A clearer (hence bug free) way to do it is-

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    cin >> num;
    arr.push_back(num);
}
```

For your second question-

> I was also wondering if using STL Arrays would be good choice or not.

I would suggest using `std::vector` here (and for most purposes).

Comment: That made the "demand for invalid input" problem disappear but the code execution still terminates after a single round of input whereas it should terminate only when the value of h is inputted as 0.

Answer (score 1):

You code has something wrong there. 
1. You should use h!=1 when you get the numbers for each permutation, in your current implementation, it is weird, if h =4, you are going to ask for 5 numbers, which does not make sense
2. You can certainly read those numbers for each test case in one line separated by space as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
   int h;
   while((cin>> h) && (h!=0))
   {
        int num;
        bool c=true;
        vector<int> arr;
        while((cin >>  std::skipws >> num) && (h!=1))
        {            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^(add this) ^^^^^^^here should be 1 not 0
           arr.push_back(num);
           --h;
        }

        const auto n = arr.size();
        for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i)
        {
            if(arr[arr[i]-1] != (i+1))
            {
                 c = false;
                 cout << "Not Ambiguous\n";
                 break;
            }
         }

         if(c==true)
             cout << "Ambiguous\n";
     }
     return 0;
}
```

However, in either cases, your results are not right, it outputs the following:

```
4
1 4 3 2
Not Ambiguous

5
2 3 4 5 1
Not Ambiguous
1
1
Ambiguous
```

While the first should be "Ambiguous", you may need to check the logic for checking ambiguity.

Comment: After making a slight change that Vinayak Garg suggested the code works fine. The only problem that I am left with is that the code execution still terminates after a single round of input whereas it should terminate only when the value of h is inputted as 0. Although I don't know why you got `Not Ambiguous` for the sequence `1 4 3 2`. It's working fine on my end.

Comment: @ChosenTorture That's so weird. I can input all 4 cases and it will output result separately on the line below the test cases. Meanwhile, when I input 0 as number of numbers, the program stops reading from prompt, which is right.

Comment: @ChosenTorture mind posting you new code such that I can run to see what happens?

Comment: I just made minor changes to the code that Vinayak Garg suggested. Check out his answer.

Comment: @ChosenTorture I changed your code as indicated by Garg. I can read all test cases unless h==0. I am using GCC 3.4.3, so really confused about why you cannot read all test cases.

Comment: I can read all the test cases now after modifying the code. The code works just as I expect it to work. You should consider upgrading your GCC compiler.